# perl string escape

Tags: string, perl, escaping

I wish to escape special characters susch as quotes and spaces in a Perl string.

I'd like to avoid using regex and installing extra modules.

Comment: Escape for what data format / language? (Escaping data for HTML is a completely different problem to escaping data for SQL, etc)

Comment: "I'd like to avoid using regex and installing extra modules." - Those are (IMO) the two biggest reasons to choose Perl in the first place. Why are you avoiding them?

Comment: Can you give perhaps an example of what you want?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what *exactly* is being asked here. Please read [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and try again.

Comment: Using regex for this situation is a really bad practice due to reinventing the wheel and the so many ways you cna forget somehting and screw up. I didn't want to install an extra module due to the fact I run my scripts on a server I don't have many permissions. So I was looking for a standard routine as @Borodin seems to have aknowledged. My real mistake was indeed not specifying what kind of escape I wanted. Thanx anyways.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [`quotemeta`](http://p3rl.org/quotemeta) may help you.

```
my $escaped = quotemeta $string_with_quotes_and_spaces;
```

which will escape with a backslash anything that isn't alphanumeric or an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving the string then Borodin's solution with quotemeta will work.

If you are declaring the string, you can use the qq switch to declare your own string delimiter. For example to use # instead of ' or ":

```
my $string = qq#Didn't know I could do this!"how" amazing#;
```

This will escape the usual string delimiters.

Comment: Yea, this doesn't really help in my situation but thanx for the tip anyhow ;)

Comment: `qq//` doesn't escape anything. It is simply a way of using delimiters other than `"` for a double-quoted string.