# perl reading from database, fields have \0 \t as normal text

Tags: perl, cgi, dbi

Apologies from the outset. I cannot give code that I am using.

I am querying a database via DBI and using perl to print the output via fetchrow-array and print $variable

But the fields in the database contain \0 \t \r etc as part of the normal text.

When these fields are printed as via the variable and the print command, these \t \r \0 text characters are mistakenly printed as tab, newline, hex character. I see no way to tell print to ignore any character strings like this.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean to say that Perl automagically translates the strings `\0`, `\t` and `\r` to null, tab and carriage return? Sounds rather unlikely. More likely, you have those characters already stored, or you are doing something which causes them to be converted.

Comment: not here: my $s = 'asd\n\t\r\0foo'; print $s; ==> asd\n\t\r\0foo

Comment: Thanks for the ultra fast replies. I am not a perl expert, heck, I wouldn't even class myself as a beginner, and it's not my code that is being used, but the output from the sql is fine, but when the sql is executed via a perl script and it's adapters(pm), the output is clearly seen to be using these as tab, newline etc etc. I can see it in the logged output, more doesn;t show it, but vi shows it, and hexdump -C shows the likes of hex code 80 where there should be \0.

Comment: So, these tabs and nulls are not showing up in `more`, but they do show up in `vi`? Well, that's... special. What I am saying is that there is no way that Perl can or will turn the literal string `\t` into a tab, unless you tell it to. If reading the string from a database, you would have to `eval` it for that to happen. What you should try is to print the output with the `Data::Dumper` module. `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper $yourvar;` This will show you the escape sequences for non-printable characters such as these.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. I will copy the pm and put that code in the copy.

Comment: @user2747269 I expect somewhere along the line you will find code with something like `eval $str`, `$str =~ s/.../$1/ee`, `qx($str)` or some such, which subjects your database strings to the lexer, causing interpolation of escape sequences.

Comment: HA!  http://www.perl.com/pub/2000/10/begperl1.html  The difference between single quotes and double quotes is that single quotes mean that their contents should be taken literally, while double quotes mean that their contents should be interpreted. For example, the character sequence \n is a newline character when it appears in a string with double quotes, but is literally the two characters, backslash and n, when it appears in single quotes.

    print "This string\nshows up on two lines.";
    print 'This string \n shows up on only one.';

Comment: @user2747269 Yes, but that is about strings that *you* type directly into Perl code, not strings that are read from other sources, such as files or databases. The principle is similar, though, that the string must pass through some sort of evaluation for escape sequences like `\t` to become tabs.

Comment: (`qx($str)` wouldn't convert `\t` to a tab, but the invoked shell might.)

Answer (score 5):

Neither fetching data using DBI nor printing will convert `\t` into a tab. The only time Perl converts `\t` is if it's found in a double-quoted string literal<sup>[1]</sup>, which is to say in a file passed to `perl`, `do`, `require` or `use`, or in a string passed to `perl -e` or `eval EXPR`.

If you have a tab, you are taking steps to convert `\t` to a tab, or it's actually a tab in the database.

---

1. This includes `qx` and the replacement expression of a substitution without `/e`.

Comment: print "$tablefield" is the line in the code that prints the tablefield, and in the tablefield we have strings like \0300InTheMorningIwillTearMyHairOutThinkingAboutThis\ThisIsHell. print "$tablefield" would then convert the \0 and the \t into hex code 80 and hex code 10/13 can't remember which.

Comment: That's not true. `print "$tablefield"` does not do any conversion whatsoever unless requested (except LF => CRLF on Windows).

Comment: @user2747269 - trust the people replying on this one. What you are describing doesn't happen. You're looking in the wrong place for the problem.

Comment: I do trust you guys, I am reading this. But if               $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper $tablefield; works, but 
print "$tablefield" doesn't, I just don;t know where else to go. I think if I can pull the variable into a function which adds escape chars to wherever in the line they need to go, and then return the variable, it might be a way around this.

Comment: @user2747269 You are confused. Data::Dumper just prints the literal representation of the whitespace characters. Those characters have already been converted, the answer is not to fix the problem downstream, but to seek it upstream. And of course, since you "cannot" show us any code, we cannot help you with that.

Comment: This link show quotemeta, which now allows the full output to be outputted.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666858/perl-string-escape

Comment: @user2747269 That only cures your symptom, sort of like putting a sticker over the "Low oil warning" lamp in your car. If you have evaluation of strings inside your code, that could lead to all sorts of problems. What I would do if I were you is to follow the data through the processing from database to final print, printing it with Data::Dumper to see where it changes, and then fix it there.

Comment: Guys, I apologise most profusely, there is other back end ksh code which echoes the output of the perl print to a file, and it looks like it is that ksh code that is causing the problem. Sorry for messing you about, and thanks for all your help.